# SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"; Incorrect syntax near "="

Tags: sql, ssms

SSMS (v 17.9) is acting stupid again kicking out bogus errors for no good reason. Incorrect syntax near "=" Any suggestions? My code is below.

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
```

Comment: SSMS doesn't usually like MySQL commands

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? As Aaron says, that's a MySQL command, and T-SQL doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Hi Aaron. Ok I didn't know that. I have received mysql stored procedures before and they were successful. Do you know if there is an online engine or converter I could use?